# Why should we use Queueable apex when we can perform chaining of batches in batch apex (when we can call another batch in the finish method)

Tags: apex, asyncapexjob

We can call another batch from the finish method of one batch, then why do we need Queueable apex

Comment: Technically, batch should be called if we are having huge data for processing. However, sometimes there are some tasks are compute intensive, which shall be called with Queueable.  And IMHO - Batch goes through different stages than queueable. Batch has start/execute[which will iterate over chunk size]/finish and next batch will be called. 

but in queueable it'll be straight forward, once you complete current processing you can initiate another processing(no need to wait for start/finish kind of stuffs).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They just have different use cases.

- Most crucially, you can have only 100 batch jobs pending at any given time. I do not believe any such limit exists for Queueable jobs.
- Queueable jobs will also tend to execute faster as they have less overhead to deal with (no start/finish).
- Generally, batches should be used to act over moderate to large database queries, whereas Queueables should be used to execute smaller increments of work more quickly.

Answer (score 6):

Queuable Advantage:

1. Queueable can run parallelly and there no limit for chaining. While in a batch there is a limit of 100 batches
2. Queueable can be much faster than batch apex if used properly
3. This can be invoked from future method as well

Batch Advantage:

1. Batch allows to query up to 50 million records in a start method (This is unique)
2. Can define the scope and can be run at a time 2000 records with batch size
3. Batch allows to track all the bulk records by using a database.stateful
4. Cannot be invoked from future method